# Bundling React Native Into a single podspec

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, podspec

I'm trying to figure out a way to instead of having to use `use_react_native` to install react native pods on IOS i'll have something like `pod 'MyReactNative'` such that `MyReactNative` would include all of the things `use_react_native` would do, or at least the end result pods that will be installed.

I Tried creating a static library in Xcode but it did not pan out as expected.